# AngularJS routing for website in subfolder - URL displaying #!/ before site page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I'm trying to set up AngularJS routing for a website inside a folder of another website. However every time I click on a link the URL displays the characters #!/ before the page name. So for example if the link for the home page is #/, when clicked on the URL redirects to #!/#%2F and encodes the forward slash. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>Appening - Photo Sharing App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/Appening/Images/favicon.png"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/png" href="/Appening/Images/applefav.png"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Appening/Styles/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Appening/Styles/styles.css"/>
    <base href="/Appening"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-controller="collapseMenuCtrl">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-ng-click="isNavCollapsed = !isNavCollapsed">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" uib-collapse="isNavCollapsed">


     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-ng-view></div>
<script src="/Appening/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Appening/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Appening/Scripts/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Appening/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Appening/Scripts/script.js"></script>
```

And here is the script.js file:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "ngAnimate", "ui.bootstrap"]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "main.html"
    })
    .when("/About", {
        templateUrl: "about.html"
    })
    .when("/Contact", {
        templateUrl: "contact.html"
    });
});
```

I set the base line in the head to the containing subfolder but still no good. This is my first time setting up Angular routing for a subdirectory, am I missing something? How do I remove the characters and successfully route to these pages without the URL redirecting?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: href's should be more like `href="#/About"` and read docs about `hashPrefix`

Comment: Hi, no they shouldn't have a forward slash after the hash, but thanks for that. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Disagree...but it's your app. As far as router path goes it is everything after `#`

Answer (score 0):

configure `$locationProvider` and set `html5Mode` to `true`.

Here is a code snippet-

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when("/", {
    templateUrl: "main.html"
})
.when("/About", {
    templateUrl: "about.html"
})
.when("/Contact", {
    templateUrl: "contact.html"
});

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

});